# What are some common functions transforming a variable on R to a variable on R+?

Tags: linear-transformations

This might be a quite simple question but I'm doing some statistics where I want to transform a variable on $\mathbb{R}$ (like the output of a linear model) to another variable on $\mathbb{R}^+$. I know there is the exponential function but for me the transformation is too uneven, in the sense that all values less than 0 are transformed to be between 0 and 1, while when the input is bigger than zero, the transformed variable will very soon reach very big values. So what are some common functions that is monotonic, and that can do a more even transformation?

Comment: I think the exponential is the best one.  It transforms addition (in $\mathbb R$) to multiplication (in $\mathbb R^+$).  Slower ones might be $e^{x/2}$ or $e^{\sqrt[3]{x}}$

Comment: Will the sigmoid function help you? $1 / (1 + \exp(-x))$. Maps $\mathbb{R}$ to the interval $(0, 1) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So I guess it has to be the exponential one way or another... Sigmoid is not exactly what I want because of course (0, 1) is part of the real number but I actually want the output domain to be all of positive reals. Thanks！